# How make layout for Samsung S2 size and another for Note2 size

Tags: android

i want to make layout for Samsung S2  size and another for Note2  size
i make multi layouts for normal and large and xlarge but s2 and note2 at the same category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For galaxy s2 the screen resolution is 480x800 while for note 2 it is 720x1280
For making layout for s2 place it in the folder layout-hdpi while for note 2 place it in layout-xhdpi

Do give a reading of official documentation here
www.developer.android.com/guide/practicesscreens_support.html

Comment: For nexus 7
layout-sw600dp
For nexus 10
layout-sw720dp
for 7 inch with resolution 480x800
layout-sw480dp

Answer (score 0):

Place the elements of your layouts in such a way that your layout will be comfortable with S2 size and Note 2 size.

Answer (score 0):

Make two layouts:

- one for Samsung Galaxy S2, which is HDPI, so use `layout-hdpi`
- another for Samsung Note II, which is xHDPI, so use `layout-xhdpi`

Comment: thanks santhosh it works for me with this answer but for tablet which layout folder i will use